# Business Objects XI 3.0 Dashboard error via Infoview

Tags: tomcat, business-objects, dashboard, infoview

I'm testing the latest Business Objects Edge Trial version, however when I'm logged in to the Infoview as the Administrator, when I click to create or organize a dashboard, I get one of the two following error messages...

Cannot forward after response has been committed

OR

Servlet Engine Exception: null
URL: /PerformanceManagement/scripts/tools/err_page.jsp?null

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bo.aa.util.SecurityStore.GetLogonToken(SecurityStore.java:28)
    at com.bo.aa.util.SecurityStore.getSecurityValue(SecurityStore.java:79)
    at com.bo.aa.impl.DBServerImpl.getSecurityToken(DBServerImpl.java:166)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.appsHome_jsp._jspService(appsHome_jsp.java:536)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution

I already have the answer to my question.

Cause: the initialization users password is incorrect

Solution: 
Create a new user with a blank password. This user is member of the Administrator's group. 
Replace the Initialization User with this a new user in the InitConfig.properties file (c:\Program Files\Business Objects\Performance Management 12.0 or ) and restart all Performance Management servers and Apache Tomcat and then log into InfoView again and the issue should now be resolved.